# Как получить изображение карты для темной темы (dark mode)?

Tags: yandex-static-maps-api

При использовании стандартного API яндекс карт имеется параметр `isNightModeEnabled` который переключает карты в тёмный режим, существует ли такая возможность для StaticApi? - в документации https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/staticapi/doc/1.x/dg/concepts/input_params-docpage/ не нашел упоминания подобной возможности, может быть есть какой-нибудь иной способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После разговора с технической поддержкой Яндекс Static API, выяснил что на текущую дату 20200622 поддержки dark mode для Static API нет и в ближайшее время не планируется, однако мне предложили вариант с использованием skl слоя (это слой инфографики - линии домов, дорог, с номерами и названиями улиц и домов. Данный слой рисуется поверх прозрачной подложки, что позволяет +- выкрутится из ситуации используя темный слой под картами.

Мне данный способ подходит.

Answer (score 1):

```
&style=stylers.lightness:invert
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]